# Why is my react on click event not firing a function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm developing a chatting app and want to add a button to delete messages. I'm using react and firebase and I want a button to delete documents from the web app with a button but I've no clue how to.

I tried:

```
  const { text, uid } = props.message;

  const messageClass = uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? "sent" : "received";

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <button onClick={firestore.collection("messages").doc().delete()}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

React returns: `Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got a value of object type.` at me and I'm clueless as to what to do.

Answer (score 1):

React onClick expects a function you should write:

```
<button onClick={() => firestore.collection("messages").doc().delete()}>
```

The reason your code fails is because you are evaluating the delete instead of passing it for react to call when you click the button.

```
<button onClick={firestore.collection("messages").doc().delete}>
```

Should also work, notice the lack of parentheses on delete.

You can read more about react events [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: The first line doesn't raise an error but it doesn't delete anything. The second line throws `Function DocumentReference.delete() requires 0 arguments, but was called with 1 argument.`

Comment: @pykrete That's because the second one will get passed the event object. For your example I would use the first one since you can ignore the event.